# how to generate multiple lines of a random list of numbers?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

Noob python learner here.. maybe just ambitious but full immersion is my way to die. But I've asked google my question 15 different ways and not finding the answer.

I've started out trying to create a pseudolist of lottery numbers. My wife's 42nd birthday is coming up and she wants to play the Powerball and/or Mega Millions. So of course, how else to learn python than to create 42 lines of randomly picked numbers in a preset range?

[Edited:] Here's what I've got so far:

```
### LOTTERY NUMBERS GENERATOR ver1.0
import random
lottery = input("Do you want to win the lottery? ")
if lottery.lower() != 'yes':
    quit()
for i in range(0, 43):
    list1 = random.sample(range(0, 70), 5) # 5 quickpick numbers between 1 and 69
    list2 = random.randint(1, 26) # 1 quickpick number between 1 and 26
print("Here are your winning lottery numbers...\n " "Ticket # " + str(i), str(list1) + " and PB " + str(list2)) ### Do this 42 times
print("GOOD LUCK!")
```

```
Currently Outputs:

Do you want to win the lottery? yes
Here are your winning lottery numbers...
 Ticket #42 [22, 20, 53, 44, 29] and PB 5
GOOD LUCK!
```

```
**I'd like for it to look like this:**

Here are your winning lottery numbers:
    
    Ticket #1 - [32, 66, 29, 17, 40] and PB 13
    Ticket #2 - [59, 2, 60, ...etc]
    Ticket #3 - etc...
    ...
    Ticket #42 - [xx, xx, xx, xx, xx] and PB xx

GOOD LUCK!
```

That's great, but everything I've tried, it spits out the same exact set of random numbers 42 times or only one line. I want 42 DIFFERENT sets. Obviously, I know I shouldn't c&p the randomizer 42 times... so how am I supposed to write out 'do this x amount of times'?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried a couple suggestions; for loop and iteration, but apparently I'm missing some understanding.

Comment: python's `random` should be initialized by calling `random.seed()` before asking it for random numbers. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_seed.asp

Comment: Random is working as it should, just thought there was something else I need to make it repeat 42 times... but with a different set of randomized numbers for each line of output. Meaning, it should generate 42 sets of random numbers between 1 and 69 for the first 5 indices, and 1 thru 26 for the "powerball" number.

Comment: You have to put it in a loop to generate multiple lines.  If you want to re-run it and get different sequences each run, @NRitH has the answer, seed the randomizer.  Plus, if you want to include 69 as a number, you should use range(1,70)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow along exactly how to "seed the randomizer"... I'll update above the new code I have and is still spitting out just one line/ticket.

Comment: This is not a problem with generating random numbers it's an issue with displaying printed lines from what you've said, most likely due to newlines not being inserted by your terminal in between each print.

Answer (score -1):

How are are you running this code?
What are you running it on?

The code as listed should produce different results each run!

You don't have to use random.seed as some have suggested, in fact doing so can make the sequence of random numbers generated repeat on each run - which is what you don't want.

If you are planning to buy 42 lines each with different random numbers you could try this..

```
import random

for i in range(1,43):

    list1 = random.sample(range(1, 69), 5)
    list2 = random.randint(1, 26)

    print("Here are your winning numbers for line " + str(i) + ": " + str(list1) + " and PB " + str(list2))

print("GOOD LUCK!")
```

This will print out 42 sets of numbers in one go.

Comment: Right now, just writing it in BBEdit and running it using Terminal on macOS. Needed something simpler than vs code or atom.

The for loops aren't working the way they've been suggested. Still only outputs one line, one "ticket"

Comment: Have you tried the short program I have suggested?
One thought is that the print outputs are being buffered and not showing up on your terminal. try adding
, flush=True)
at the end of the print statements..
e.g.
print("Here are your winning numbers for line " + str(i) + ": " + str(list1) + " and PB " + str(list2), flush=True)

Comment: Try pasting the code to an online python interpreter:
https://www.online-python.com/
Then work out what is wrong with your set up!

Comment: it still prints just one line... but prints the 42.
```
Do you want to win the lottery? yes
Here are your winning lottery numbers for ticket 42: [17, 41, 68, 37, 33] and PB 8
GOOD LUCK!
```

Comment: This sounds like something odd with your terminal, maybe the other lines are scrolling off screen or getting over-written. Try the following and watch the display. Here we have a pause between subsequent lines, do you see 1..41 this way?

import random, time

for i in range(1,43):

    list1 = random.sample(range(1, 69), 5)
    list2 = random.randint(1, 26)

    print("Here are your winning numbers for line " + str(i) + ": " + str(list1) + " and PB " + str(list2),flush=True)
    time.sleep(2)
print("GOOD LUCK!")

Comment: try adding print("\n\r") after the line print("Here are your..")

I'm wondering if your terminal is not generating new lines after each print and therefore over writing previous prints?

Comment: Does exactly the same thing on the online IDE. Only prints out ticket #42.

Comment: LOL are you kidding? Do you have a very narrow pair of glasses on or something?
Just tried pasting the above code into my browser here..
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

..and it works fine!

Comment: Here's another online python with the code shared..
https://onlinegdb.com/FYIx44eYV

Comment: Not sure why it's not working my setup but just tried it on programiz.com not working... but works only on onlinegdb.com !??

Comment: Ok you now have a different question to raise on SO, we have solved how to generate multiple lines of random numbers in Python for you! I'm guessing you have a mac specific issue with subsequent lines not being printed from Python, very curious why it doesn't work in an in-browser IDE as that should be sandboxed from the rest of your OS?

Comment: I found the silly little bug... there was a hiding \spacebar in the for loop! I didn't see it until I copied your shared code on onlinegdb.. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes white space is VERY important in Python!!
It defines what is and what is not included in the loop, so I'm guessing you had the print line outside of the loop and therefore only printed once after the last iteration!
Glad you found it but please get yourself a decent IDE like VsCode with a good linter like PyLance installed, it will save you from all these little horrors!

Comment: I have vscode and pycharm. So much info out there that I'm overwhelmed with all these add-ons and fluff. I like the simplest of things. I just wanted to get started right away. Thank you so much for the push in the right direction. I'll be visiting here more often as I progress and gain more xp points!